# Django Variable Wrapped in Paragraph Tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-ckeditor

I am using django-ckeditor as a WYSIWYG text editor when creating posts. It captures and saves the content and the correct HTML tags without any problem. However, my template renders the variable surrounded by `<p>` tags, which ruins the RichTextField because `<p>` tags cannot be nested. As a result, it was showing all of the text (with tags) as a paragraph with no formatting. I realized that this was happening, so I changed the surrounding tags in my template to `<div>` tags, but when the template is loaded on the browser, it replaces the div tags with paragraph tags again. How can I get rid of the `<p>` tags so that my text is rendered with the correct formatting?

Here is my template:

```
{% extends 'bandwagon/base.html' %}  
{% block content %}
    <article class="media content-section">
        <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="profile photo" class="rounded-circle article-img">
        <div class="media-body">
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="post-img">
            <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted | date:'F d, Y'}}</small>
                {% if object.author == user %}
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1">Edit</a>
                    <a href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1">Delete</a>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <h2 class='article-title-detail'>{{ object.title }}</h2>
            <div class="article-content">{{ object.content | safe }}</div>
        </div>
    </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

However, in the browser, the response is this:

```
            <p class="article-content">&lt;h3&gt;Fake Content&lt;/h3&gt;

&lt;h3&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size:13px&quot;&gt;Fake Content&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h3&gt;</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default CKEditor RichTextField adds `<p>` tags around the content of the field.

 
If that's the reason you keep seeing `<p>` around your content, you can customizing your CKEditor editor, so it will not add the `<p>` like this:

```
#base.py
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'autoParagraph': False
    },
}
```

You can also create a specific configuration and set specific fields to use it.
read more about it here: https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#optional-customizing-ckeditor-editor

Comment: Doesn't work with the latest version of Django and CKEditor.